# Resulting table off page limits

Tags: tables

everyone,

I've been trying to build a timetable in LaTeX but the resulting table is off. Could somebody help me out?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
  Aula & Diurno & Noturno & Professor & Conteúdo\\
  \hline
  1 & 01 Ago & 02 Ago & DM & Introducao, contagem de alelos, equilibrio de Hardy Weinberg\\
  2 & 08 Ago & 09 Ago & DM & Deriva genética \textbf{Pratica}: simulacao de deriva com feijao\\
  3 & 15 Ago & 16 Ago & DM & Deriva genética, tamanho efetivo e teoria neutra\\
  4 & 22 Ago & 23 Ago & DM & Introdução a seleção natural \textbf{Prática}: modelos determinísticos de seleção\\
  5 & 29 Ago & 30 Ago & DM & Integração de processos evolutivas: ação conjunta de seleção, deriva e migração \textbf{Prática}: simulações de seleção e deriva no Populus\\
  & 05 Set & 06 Set & & Feriado\\
  6 & 12 Set & 13 Set & DM & Evolução do genoma e desequilibrio de ligação\\
  7 & 19 Set & 20 Set & Glauco + DM & Evolução do sexo\\
  8 & 26 Set & 27 Set & & Prova 1\\
  & 03 Out & 04 Out & & Semana Temática\\
  & 10 Out & 11 Out & & Feriado\\
  9 & 17 Out & 18 Out & GM & Genética quantitativa e o conceito de herdabilidade\\
  10 & 24 Out & 25 Out & GM & Adaptação e genética e loci de caracteres quantitativos (QTLs)\\
  11 & 31 Out & 01 Nov & GM & Adaptação e processos evolutivos em caracteres contínuos\\
  12 & 07 Nov & 08 Nov & GM & Unidade de Seleção\\
  & 14 Nov & 15 Nov & & Feriado\\
  13 & 21 Nov & 22 Nov & GM & Conceito de espécie e especiação \\
  14 & 28 Nov & 29 Nov & GM & Macroevolução: coevolução e desenvolvimento\\
  15 & 05 Dez & 06 Dez & & Prova 2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `l`,`r` and `c` columns wont wrap lines, whereas `p` columns will, so you could try something like `\begin{tabular}{rrrp{1.5cm}p{5cm}}`.

Comment: oops, I can't upvote in this forum, but thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `tabularx` environment. I took the liberty to change some alignments and changed the shade of grey, as I found them nicer, used the rules  from `booktabs`, and increased the value of `\arraystretch` to have some vertical padding around the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,  booktabs}

 \begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\rowcolors{1}{}{Lavender}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rlcr >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
  \toprule
  Aula & Diurno & Noturno & Professor & Conteúdo\\
  \midrule
  1 & 01 Ago & 02 Ago & DM & Introducao, contagem de alelos, equilibrio de Hardy Weinberg\\
  2 & 08 Ago & 09 Ago & DM & Deriva genética \textbf{Pratica}: simulacao de deriva com feijao\\
  3 & 15 Ago & 16 Ago & DM & Deriva genética, tamanho efetivo e teoria neutra\\
  4 & 22 Ago & 23 Ago & DM & Introdução a seleção natural \textbf{Prática}: modelos determinísticos de seleção\\
  5 & 29 Ago & 30 Ago & DM & Integração de processos evolutivas: ação conjunta de seleção, deriva e migração \textbf{Prática}: simulações de seleção e deriva no Populus\\
  & 05 Set & 06 Set & & Feriado\\
  6 & 12 Set & 13 Set & DM & Evolução do genoma e desequilibrio de ligação\\
  7 & 19 Set & 20 Set & Glauco + DM & Evolução do sexo\\
  8 & 26 Set & 27 Set & & Prova 1\\
  & 03 Out & 04 Out & & Semana Temática\\
  & 10 Out & 11 Out & & Feriado\\
  9 & 17 Out & 18 Out & GM & Genética quantitativa e o conceito de herdabilidade\\
  10 & 24 Out & 25 Out & GM & Adaptação e genética e loci de caracteres quantitativos (QTLs)\\
  11 & 31 Out & 01 Nov & GM & Adaptação e processos evolutivos em caracteres contínuos\\
  12 & 07 Nov & 08 Nov & GM & Unidade de Seleção\\
  & 14 Nov & 15 Nov & & Feriado\\
  13 & 21 Nov & 22 Nov & GM & Conceito de espécie e especiação \\
  14 & 28 Nov & 29 Nov & GM & Macroevolução: coevolução e desenvolvimento\\
  15 & 05 Dez & 06 Dez & & Prova 2\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]